# Simulate stdout in fake subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, testing, mocking, subprocess

I would like to test a function, which invokes `subprocess.Popen` and captures `stdout`. In particular, I need to test `stdout` content physically captured in a file on disc without ever calling the actual process.

Sample function:

```py
import subprocess

def func():
    with open('stdout.txt', 'wt') as out:
        subprocess.Popen(_cmdline(), stdout=out)

def _cmdline() -> list[str]:
    # Or whatever process we want to run
    return ['ls']
```

Test function:

```py
from unittest import mock

def test_captures_stdout():
    with mock.patch('subprocess.Popen') as mock_popen:
        func()

    # Try to intercept stdout and write to it
    [(_, kwargs)] = mock_popen.call_args_list
    with kwargs['stdout']:
        buf.write('some standard output')

    with open('stdout.txt') as buf:
        assert buf.read() == 'some standard output'
```

Here I mock `subprocess.Popen`, then I intercept `stdout` passed to its constructor and try to write to the buffer. Then I intend to run assertions on the content of `stdout.txt` file.

Apparently, when I try to write to `stdout` buffer, it is already closed and I get IO error.

```
================================== FAILURES ===================================
____________________________ test_captures_stdout _____________________________

    def test_captures_stdout():
        with mock.patch('subprocess.Popen') as mock_popen:
            func()

        # Try to intercept stdout and write to it
        [(_, kwargs)] = mock_popen.call_args_list
>       with kwargs['stdout']:
E       ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

test_subprocess.py:22: ValueError
=========================== short test summary info ===========================
```

I wonder if there is a convenient way of mocking `Popen` and somehow simulating `stdout` written to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your unit test as it is is rather pointless since it writes test content directly to the file object on its own after `func` returns, so not only is the file object already closed and therefore invalid, but any logics after the call to `Popen` that rely on the output content would not work since no content is written to the file object during the call to `func`.

You can instead patch `Popen` with a [side effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) of a function that mocks the `Popen` constructor by writing test content to the given `stdout` file object:

```
def test_captures_stdout():
    def mock_popen(cmd, stdout, **kwargs):
        stdout.write('some standard output')

    with mock.patch('subprocess.Popen', autospec=True, side_effect=mock_popen):
        func()

    with open('stdout.txt') as buf:
        assert buf.read() == 'some standard output'
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/FuchsiaMerryScandisk

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Although, this is a valid suggestion, it limits the signature of Popen to mock_popen. In reality I will have other keyword arguments, which are not listed in the original (simplified version). What if I want to use autospec=True to ensure that the signature is correct?

Comment: Thanks for the updated and extended answer!

Comment: Yes, you can still specify `autospec=True` to make the mock object returned by `patch` compatible with `Popen` in signature. Since `mock_popen` accepts `**kwargs`, it should be compatible with any call as well.